# Usage of stream.Transform.from

Tags: node.js, stream, node-streams

I want to quickly declare a transform stream without any additional libraries. Making async generators into transform streams via `stream.Transform.from` looks like a good choice.

```
someReadable.pipe(
        stream.Transform.from(async function* (source, writable) {
          for await (const chunk of source) {
            yield JSON.stringify(chunk, null, 2) + "\n\n";
          }
        })
      )
```

Why does the above not work?

TypeScript throws:

```
Error:(8, 9) TS2345: Argument of type 'Readable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableStream'.
  Type 'Readable' is missing the following properties from type 'WritableStream': writable, write, end
```

```
Error:(8, 31) TS2345: Argument of type '(source: any, writable: any) => AsyncGenerator<string, void, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<any> | AsyncIterable<any>'.
  Property '[Symbol.asyncIterator]' is missing in type '(source: any, writable: any) => AsyncGenerator<string, void, unknown>' but required in type 'AsyncIterable<any>'.
```

```
Error:(14, 8) TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'WritableStream'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` function is not actually from the `Transform` class. `Transform` is a child class of `Duplex` which is a child of `Readable` and `Writable`. The only `.from` function in the `stream` module is the [`Readable.from`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_readable_from_iterable_options) function, so you're actually calling that.

You can verify this yourself:

```
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v12.14.0.
Type ".help" for more information.

> const stream = require('stream')
> stream.Readable.from === stream.Transform.from
true
```

Unfortunately, the `stream` module does not appear to have `Transform.from` or `Writable.from`.

From https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_types_of_streams:

> Additionally, this module includes the utility functions `stream.pipeline()`, `stream.finished()` and `stream.Readable.from()`.

Answer (score 1):

With the new experimental `stream.compose` API you can convert async iterables, generators and functions into streams. Example from [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_compose_streams):

```js
import { compose } from 'stream';
import { finished } from 'stream/promises';

// Convert AsyncIterable into readable Duplex.
const s1 = compose(async function*() {
  yield 'Hello';
  yield 'World';
}());

// Convert AsyncGenerator into transform Duplex.
const s2 = compose(async function*(source) {
  for await (const chunk of source) {
    yield String(chunk).toUpperCase();
  }
});

let res = '';

// Convert AsyncFunction into writable Duplex.
const s3 = compose(async function(source) {
  for await (const chunk of source) {
    res += chunk;
  }
});

await finished(compose(s1, s2, s3));

console.log(res); // prints 'HELLOWORLD'
```

[Source](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_compose_streams)

Comment: Consider putting instructions in your answer instead of just providing a link.